# Unable to upload external java library to Git from Netbeans

Tags: java, git, netbeans, push

I have a Java Web project on Netbeans which uses external "java-json.jar" library.
I set up a git remote repository and pushing my project from netbeans. Everything get pushed into the repo except my external libraries.

How to enable pushing external library as well?

Comment: Please check `.gitignore` file in your repository

Comment: There is no .gitignore file in my repository

Comment: Maybe it's hidden? Please try run command in console: `git check-ignore -v java-json.jar` or `git check-ignore -v *.jar`. If will show an actual rule that makes a file to be ignored

Comment: No hidden file and the command shows no output. I checked it in the root of my project directory. Also I'm on Windows OS if it adds up to anything

Comment: Where does the external library live in your project structure? Are you using Ant (hope not) or Maven ?

Comment: The external library was not in my project directory. Copying it in solved the problem for me. :) Thanks a lot for help!